# Window Azure Virtual Network: Asp.net can not access to shared folder from other virtual machine

Tags: asp.net, azure

In window azure portal, I've created a virtual network and then add a virtual machine (X) and a cloud service (Y) into that network.

Within cloud service machine Y, I am able to access to the shared folder in virtual machine X by window explorer.

The problem is I can not access that shared folder from my cloud service - web application.

Error returned:

```
Access to the path '\\10.0.1.5\Upload\test.txt' is denied.
Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '\\10.0.1.5\Upload\test.txt' is denied.
ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7, and the configured application pool identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if the application is not impersonating. If the application is impersonating via <identity impersonate="true"/>, the identity will be the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated request user.
```

I did grant full permission access to that shared folder (everyone, network service, iis_iusr, ...) but no luck.

When I add the impersonate identity to the web.config with specific username & password:

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="username" password="pass" />
```

Then I got this error:

```
 Could not find file '\\10.0.1.5\Upload\test.txt'.
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. The impersonate as described above works just fine. My mistake is the filename does accidentally  have duplicated ext (test.txt.txt) .